# Tumblr API - List a user's tumblogs? PHP

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

I'm having trouble finding out how to list an authorized user's Tumblr blogs in [Tumblr's API documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2). As you all know, Tumblr allows users to create a bunch of different "tumblogs" in one account. How do I find out what other tumblogs the user has? I want to list it so that the user can pick which one to post to. I'm using PHP and [TumblrOAuth](https://github.com/jacobbudin/tumblroauth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, nevermind, I kept on looking at the Blog Info section, the details for listing the user's blogs are at the User Methods section.